# Как объединить сразу больше трёх коллекций

Tags: c#

объединяются данные типа `IEnumerable<string>`

```
var a = Files1.Concat(Files2);
a = a.Concat(LocalFiles);
```

Concat приходится объединять по две

Comment: Последовательный вызов `Concat` не подходит? `var a = Files1.Concat(Files2).Concat(LocalFiles)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать такой фокус

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources)
    {
        foreach (var source in sources)
            foreach (var item in source)
                yield return item;
    }
}
```

Вроде работает

```
void Main()
{
    var sample = Enumerable.Range(1, 3);

    var result = IEnumerableExtensions.Concat(sample, sample.Reverse(), 
            new[] {4, 5, 2 , 6}, new[] {4, 5, 6});  

    // Ну, или просто последовательный Concat, как советовали в комментах
    var result2 = sample
                    .Concat(sample.Reverse())
                    .Concat(new[] {4, 5, 2 , 6})
                    .Concat(new[] {4, 5, 6});   
}
```

P.S
Еще более короткий вариант от PetSerAl

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{       
    public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources) 
                => sources.SelectMany(x => x);
}
```

Comment: @Андрей ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: С yield даже получше будет, чем несколько Concat

Comment: Можно сократить по идее, если вместо вложенного цикла возвращать `yield return source.GetEnumerator();`

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk да, по сути, примерно одно и то же. Там под капотом Concat'a подобная конструкция.

Comment: @Андрей Зачем сокращать, и так код вроде не громоздкий и понятный :)

Comment: @tym32167 я почему-то думал, что Concat не отложенная операция

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,686

Comment: `public static IEnumerable<T> Concat<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sources) => sources.SelectMany(x => x);`

Comment: @PetSerAl Согласен, обновил ответ